# Mongodb Group stage, and query last two document

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb, if we want to take first or last document of the group stage, then the FIRST and LAST operator will helpful. I want to group the collection based on _id:"$department" and also take the LAST document and the LAST-1 document. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have this collection:

```
[
  { department: "HR", employees: 20 },
  { department: "Finance", employees: 30 },
  { department: "Sales", employees: 5 },
  { department: "IT", employees: 50 }
]
```

Then you can run this aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { department: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         employees: { $sum: "$employees" },
         all_departments: { $push: "$department" }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         last_departments: {
            $concatArrays: [
               [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$all_departments", -1] }],
               [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$all_departments", -2] }]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

Mongo [Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CY9CPVz04gF)

**Update**

With [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html) it is even shorter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $sort: { department: 1 } },
   {
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         employees: { $sum: "$employees" },
         all_departments: { $push: "$department" }
      }
   },
   { $set: { last_departments: { $slice: ["$all_departments", -2] } } }
])
```